Web Server Socket Programming Only Work 80 porty

from socket import *
import sys

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) 
serverPort = 100 

serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort)) 

serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:

    connectionSocket,addr = serverSocket.accept() 
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(4096).decode()
        filename = message.split()[1][1:]
        with open(filename,"rb") as f:
            output = f.read()

        print(output)

        
        connectionSocket.sendall(output)
        print("Sent successfully.")
        connectionSocket.close()

    except:
        response = b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \r\n\r\n" 
        connectionSocket.send(response)
        connectionSocket.close()

serverSocket.close()

you see a web server code made with socket programming. This code works properly when we specify port 80. but if I change the port to for example 100. On the console it says sent successfully. But on the web side I get this error ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE. What do you think could be the reason?

if you run code on some servers then they may block some ports - to stop hackers.

maybe you should use logging to save in file information which part of code was executed and what it had in variables - and later you can check logs to see if server works correctly.

How exactly you access the server? And what exactly do you send back to the client, i.e. what is the content of the files read from disk. Note that you don't explicitly add a HTTP header when sending the files, so it should be contained in the files themselves because otherwise it is a wrong HTTP response. It might be that the client still accepts old HTTP/0.9 style responses w/o HTTP header when accessing the server on port 80 for compatibility reasons with old historic servers, but not on other ports.
